# What are some ways to control a device through an IP address?

Tags: c, networking, rest, soa, messaging

I want to get some ideas on how I might control a video camera through an IP address.  I have an API to control pan and tilt from a local machine.  The code is going to be in C/C++ on Windows.  I am still designing if I want multiple cameras controlled from one application or have a one camera to one application.  Would SOA be a useful architecture to structure my messaging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could be well served by something like [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) for a task like this. Executing a command towards a REST server is really intuitive and simple, which sounds just like what you need. I'd probably make some kind of application that would be running inside a web-server, since this would handle most of the infrastructure, including authentication if needed. I'm sure both apache and IIS could do this for you quite easily. Even though your API is coded in C you could also consider using some higher-level scripting language as a client to the API (inside the web server).

SOA sounds a little overkill for a task like this.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar for aproject in my university. What we had was the cameras connected to a LAN and with message passing was very easy to communicate with them, is the same that communicate with any PC. We had the same application to communicate them. You can use SOA or any architecture you consider convinient, that depens on your application.

For our case was just an ad hoc architecture, it was not a complex thing.

Comment: hi, I'm trying to connect to a dvr which is connected to several cameras for iphone. Can you please tell me how you did it? Any guidance will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hessian is nice. It is basically REST, but has a binary protocol which is more efficient than XML and it also lets you make calls from other languages quite easily. So, you could develop the client GUI applciation in C# and the server in C. There are free libraries for a few different languages available.

http://hessian.caucho.com/